# Regenerations in a game

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is for regenerating some things in a game a made. The code is very big and I think it can be compressed but I don't know how to do it.

```vb
Private Sub regen()

    'regen coins
    z = coin1



     z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()


    z = coin2


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin3


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin4


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin5


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin6


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin7


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin8


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin9

    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin10


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin11


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin12


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin13


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin14


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin15


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin16


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin17


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin18


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin19


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin20


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin21


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin22


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin23


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin24


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin25


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin26


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin27


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin28


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin29


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin30


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin31


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    z = coin32


    z.Location = zloc
    z.Hide()
    zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If zloc.Y > 595 Then
        zloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    z.Location = zloc
    z.Show()

    'regen medcoins

    p = medcoin1


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin2

    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin3


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin4


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin5


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin6


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()

    p = medcoin7


    p.Location = ploc
    p.Hide()
    ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If ploc.Y > 595 Then
        ploc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    p.Location = ploc
    p.Show()



    'regens hcoins

    h = hcoin1


    h.Location = hloc
    h.Hide()
    hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If hloc.Y > 595 Then
        hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    h.Location = hloc
    h.Show()

    h = hcoin2



    h.Location = hloc
    h.Hide()
    hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If hloc.Y > 595 Then
        hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    h.Location = hloc
    h.Show()

    h = hcoin3


    h.Location = hloc
    h.Hide()
    hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    If hloc.Y > 595 Then
        hloc = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End If
    h.Location = hloc
    h.Show()



End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you heard of functions?  The easiest way to shorten this is to take the repeated code, put it in a function, then call the function with all your coins.

You should make the if statement a loop.  As it currently is coded, what happens if the 2nd try > 595?

```
Private Sub PlaceCoin(Coin coin)

    Coin.Hide()
    Point location = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))

    While location.Y > 595
        location = New Point(RandomNumber(playspace.Width), RandomNumber(playspace.Height))
    End While

    Coin.Location = location
    Coin.Show()

End Sub
```

Then you would call it from your RegenCoins Sub

```
Private Sub RegenCoins()

    PlaceCoin(coin1)
    PlaceCoin(coin2)
    'etc..

End Sub
```

You could also put your coins into an array or list

```
Private Coin coins(NumberOfCoins)

For Each coin In coins
    PlaceCoin coin
Next
```

Comment: This will also make it easier to change the RegenCoins logic because one change, will change the logic for every coin rather than having to go through x number of lines of code to make the same change.  One more suggestion: get rid of the magic number 595.  It should be either a constant, a configurable value, or a calculated (assuming it is the size of the screen) value.